# How can I produce sentences response with AI when I use my own data to train the model?

Tags: keras, chatbot

I have trained a model in KERAS with my own text data from OneNote notices.
Now, when I use the model.predict function with a question as an input, I receive as return data an array with 5700 elements with some probabilities. Now I don't how can I generate a meaningful reply from my model.
I tried to find a solution, so I used the 10 maximum probabilities to generate a sentence but the result is ridiculous.
I use the following model

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Embedding(total_words, 100, input_length=max_sequence_length),
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4),
tf.keras.layers.LSTM(150),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(total_words, activation='softmax')
])
```

Could anyone help me with my issue or give me any tip?

Comment: You should decode tokens autoregressively. Check the `decode_sequence` function in the [Keras tutorial on sequence-to-sequence learning](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html) to have an idea of how a basic decoding strategy (i.e. greedy decoding) it looks like.

Comment: @noe I think this example is old, because uses character encoding and not word encoding. Also is not explain in details how the decoding is working.

Comment: In that tutorial, there is a section called "What if I want to use a word-level model with integer sequences?"